# Get CPU usage for specific process for sandbox enabled MAS App (Objective C- Xcode)

Tags: macos, cpu

I 'm working on a Mac App (Objective C) which I wanna distribute over the Mac App Store.
I'm using NSWorkspace to get all running applications.
What I want is to get the CPU usage % for each process identifier of all running applications.
Now I'm doing it with NSTask and  NSPipe using the top command. This works perfect when App Sandboxing is disabled.
When App Sandboxing is enabled I get the following error: Couldn't posix_spawn: error 1
Is there anything I can do to make this work with App Sandboxing on? Is there another way to get CPU usage for a specific PID, without using NSTask and top or ps ?

Thanks for your help.

Steve

Comment: I'm also having same problem. Did you get any solution?